# Sonata user bundle creates 4 tables

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata

I have had FosUser bundle before and today installed SonataUserBundle. When I --dump-sql, Symfony wants to install 4 new tables:

```
fos_user_user
fos_user_group
for_user_user_group
notification_message
```

First 3 are confusing because admin already works using existing ...Entity\User class for which I even set relations.

```
namespace Rent\ProgramBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="tbl_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
...
```

Why these 3 tables are installed and how to prevent that? Is there any use for them because admin section is working even without them.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the SonataAdminBundle does not come with any user management, however it is most likely the application requires such feature. The Sonata Project includes a SonataUserBundle which integrates the FOSUserBundle.

The FOSUserBundle adds support for a database-backed user system in Symfony2. It provides a flexible framework for user management that aims to handle common tasks such as user login, registration and password retrieval.

The SonataUserBundle is just a thin wrapper to include the FOSUserBundle into the AdminBundle. The SonataUserBundle includes :

- A default login area
- A default user_block template which is used to display the current
  user and the logout link
- 2 Admin classes : User and Group
- A default class for User and Group.

There is a little magic in the SonataAdminBundle : if the bundle detects the SonataUserBundle class, then the default user_block template will be changed to use the one provided by the SonataUserBundle.

Please take a look to this [document](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html). Hope it is helpfull.